# Load from multiple remote pages?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a code that automatically counts the members in a particular member group of my forum (Proboards to be exact). Member names are in  tags labeled with classes of group0, group1 and so forth. So, what I did was to call all the names from the View All Members page to automatically gain a member count.

However, I found out that the View All Members page can only display a maximum of 200 names per page. Hence, if my forum was to exceed the total member count of 200, it wouldn't be able to include the members appearing on the succeeding pages in the count.

So I'm asking, is it possible to load elements from two or more remote pages?

Btw, here's how my code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('<div></div>').load("/index.cgi?action=members&view=all&perpage=200 a[class^='group']", function () {
    $('#result1').text( $('a.group1', this).length );
    $('#result2').text( $('a.group2', this).length );
  });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $.get within a loop to get multiple pages, and then store the information within those pages in a variable (each loop iteration could just add to the variable).

One change you would have to make is how you get the information parsed out of the page because $.get does not allow you to retrieve page fragments with selectors (like your "a[class^='group']" selector).

```
var counter = 1;
var all_data = "";
while (counter < 5) {
    $.get('/index.cgi?action=members&view=all&perpage=200', function (data) {
        all_data += data;
    });
    counter++;
}
```

Some Notes:

- You can use the counter variable to increment the page that you are retrieving so each iteration of the while loop will get a new page of member listings.
- The data variable within the anonymous function that deals with the response from the ajax request is the full page (as I stated above, page fragments cannot be retrieved using $.get) however you can parse this information down to what you want before saving it to the all_data variable.
- Instead of saving the data to the all_data variable you could just add it to the dom as it comes in.

Here is the related documentation for JQuery:

$.get() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

load() - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to jquery. I don't understand any of it yet. :( So where do I insert the second and succeeding url's?

Comment: OMG I MADE IT WORK MYSELF. LIKE FINALLY. THANK YOU VERY MUCH. HAPPY HAPPY HAPPY

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 1;
var all_data = "";
while (counter < 7) {
    $.get('/index.cgi?action=members&view=all&perpage=200&page=' + counter, function (data) {
        all_data += data;
$('#result0').text( $('a.group0', all_data).length );
$('#result1').text( $('a.group1', all_data).length );
$('#result2').text( $('a.group2', all_data).length );
$('#result3').text( $('a.group3', all_data).length );
    });
    counter++;
}

});`